# How can I filter out the coordinates which make similar polygons on a graph in Python?

Tags: python, geometry, polygon

This is the coordinate list which is being generated in a text file:

```
-1603112 -2785117
-1602727 -2785305
-1600754 -2780565
-1600754 -2786134
-1600752 -2786134
-1600752 -2780560
-1600154 -2779123
-1600356 -2779472
-1600752 -2780283
-1600752 -2780159
-1600754 -2780162
-1600754 -2780287
```

Comment: This is unclear. Say you have 4 vertices of a square. Any three of them make a triangle which is similar to every other triangle made by three points -- do you filter out all coordinates so that you are left with the empty list? What does is even mean to filter a list with a predicate that applies to pairs of subsets of the list rather than individual elements?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you have coordinate pairs within the text file you were mentioning (not just a list of negative values as it looks like in the paragraph above).  The pairings would look something like this:

```
[
(-1603112, -2785117),
(-1602727, -2785305),
(-1600754, -2780565),
...etc..
]
```

With these pairings, you'd construct the polygons you'd like to test for (not sure about the shape/size here since you can connect as many pairs as you want to above) and then test for "similarity" (whether that's in shape/angles/volume etc. -- you'll probably need to be more specific).  If you could confirm the coordinate pairing assumptions above and what tests for similarity you'd like to perform, I can help answer the question further.